limit as n approaches infinity of $1+(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}$
How do I approach this problem? I need to find the limit of the following sequence
$$
\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 1+(-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
I know that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} 1+ \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = 1$. My problem is the $(-1)^n$, what do I do with it? I know that it makes the series non monotonic, but the oscillation around 1 decreases as n grows. How do I prove this, how do I write this out?
EDIT: Is this the right way to solve this?
$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{1}{n^2}$
$1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$
$1-0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1+0$
$1 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1$
$ \underline{\underline{\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} =1}}$

Start by computing $\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$

You can remark that $1 - \frac{1}{n^2} \leqslant u_n \leqslant 1+\frac{1}{n^2}$ where $(u_n)$ is your sequence. This yields $|u_n -1| \leqslant \frac{1}{n^2}$

You could simply use the fact that both $1$ and $\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ converge, and then compute both limits separately.

@MartinR how do I compute the limit of that?

HINT
I would recommend you to apply the squeeze theorem to the second term since the sequence given by $a_{n} = (-1)^{n}$ is bounded and the sequence $b_{n} = 1/n^{2}$ converges to zero.
Can you take it from here?

Is this right?
$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1-\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+\frac{1}{n^2}$
$1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$
$1-0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1+0$
$1 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 1$
$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1+(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2} =1$

That's right! You have just applied the squeeze theorem.

Actually, $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$.
So the sequence $\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right\} $is an infinitesimal sequence.

Yes you are correct. Try to look carefully at your limit. Your limit is $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+(-1)^{n}×\frac{1}{n^{2}})$$
Now you know that $(-1)^{1}=(-1)^{3}=(-1)^{5}=....=-1$ and $(-1)^{2}=(-1)^{4}=(-1)^{6}=....=1$
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^{n}$$ is undefined.
But if you take into consideration your limit then $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}=0$$ Why ? Because $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^{n}=$$ {$-1,1$} and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=0$$.
Therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{-1}{n^{2}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}=0$$
Therefore the correct answer to your limit is $1$. Because $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}=0$$
